# background images and cover images disappear on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

the website that I'm working has a background image for the footer that is not showing on mobiles and tablets. It was working perfectly before. I checked everything 1000 times and can't find the problem. The same thing happened with the section background cover image.
You can view the page here: http://amapolapr.com/Amapola-New/receta-bacalaitos.html
HTML:
        
        
        
        Paseando por las costas de Puerto Rico encuentras los kioscos o "chinchorros" que ofrecen deliciosos antojitos tipicos puertorriqueños como bacalaitos fritos, mariscos, tostones de plátano, alcapurrias y bebidas de toda clase.

```
    <!-- footer begin -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="images/Logo_Molinos.png" alt="Molinos de PR logo"><br/><br/>
                    P&aacute;gina oficial Molinos de Puerto Rico. 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="widget widget_recent_post">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="social">
                        <h3>S&iacute;guenos</h3>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="color:#363535 !important; font-size:36px;"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="color:#363535 !important; font-size:36px;"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3>Contacto</h3>
                    <div class="widget widget-address">
                        <address>
                            Molinos de Puerto Rico<br> San Juan, Puerto Rico 00921<br>
                            <span><strong>Phone: </strong>(787) 123-4567</span><br>
                            <span><strong>Fax: </strong>(787) 123-4567</span><br>
                            <span><a href="mailto:lc@krativeadpr.com" style="color:#363535">Envíanos un email</a></span>
                        </address>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="subfooter">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        &copy; Copyright 2015 - Molinos de Puerto Rico.                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs">
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="aboutus.html">Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="recetas.html">Recetas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Comunidad</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>
    <!-- footer close -->
```

CSS:

```
 #frase3 { 
        background-image:url('../images/Kioscos-3.jpg');
        background-size:cover !important;
        min-height: 500px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
  }
```

Thank you !

Comment: your background image is wrap in @media (min-width: 1200px)

Comment: so it will only show if your screen is bigger than 1200px.

Comment: please forgive my tired eyes… but I can't find where is that...

Comment: search for `@media (min-width: 1200px)`  in your style.css, you missing a `{` somewhere there

Comment: @ line 403 of your style.css

Comment: `@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 .timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
  margin-top: -50px;
}` you are missing `}`

Comment: Also on the footer the background image isn't showing… is the same problem?

Comment: most likely that's the case.

Comment: yes it should be the problem because is the last thing I did, the timeline.

Comment: Wow! You have no idea how much time I lost with this missing a closing }!!!!! Thank you very very much, I guess is time to go to sleep a little bit!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the media query from `@media (min-width: 1200px) #frase3` to make it `#frase3` and you should be all sorted.

For future help, try resizing your browser window on a system you think it is functioning well in. It will highlight any problems like this one and reveal that it is not a device specific problem which helps you debug the problem.

It's at line 403 by looks of things:
[image: Screenshot of webpage inspecting the relevant image]